# SQL Server 2005 - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

This code:

```
USE [db]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetFieldPickerReports]    Script Date: 01/11/2013 19:12:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFieldPickerReports] (@CustomerName  varchar(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
  RETURN SELECT [fpr].[ID], [fpr].[Name], [fpr].[Global], [fpr].[FPRCategoryID]
  FROM FieldPickerReport fpr, dbo.GetProductKeyIdByCustomer(@CustomerName) pk 
  LEFT JOIN [FPRCategory] fprcat on ([fpr].[FPRCategoryID]=[fprcat].[ID])
  WHERE [Global]=1 OR ProductKeyID=pk.id
```

Produces an error:

> The multi-part identifier "fpr.FPRCategoryID" could not be bound.

This query works without the `Left Join` (which I currently need to add) or either with the removal of `dbo.GetProductKeyIdByCustomer()` and the `Where` clause.

Here's the code for `dbo.GetProductKeyIdByCustomer()`

```
USE [db]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetProductKeyIdByCustomer]    Script Date: 01/11/2013 19:58:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProductKeyIdByCustomer] (@CustomerName  varchar(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN SELECT id
   FROM ProductKey
   WHERE [CustomerName]=@CustomerName AND Enabled=1
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Is there a logic to which names you put in square brackets?

Comment: @MrLister Maybe the previous developer with whom i have no contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think that these UDFs would be better implemented as Views.

Second, you are mixing implicit and explicit joins.  Using all explicit joins should solve your issue:

```
SELECT 
    [fpr].[ID], 
    [fpr].[Name], 
    [fpr].[Global], 
    [fpr].[FPRCategoryID]
FROM 
    FieldPickerReport fpr
    JOIN dbo.GetProductKeyIdByCustomer(@CustomerName) pk 
        ON [Global] = 1 OR ProductKeyID = pk.id
    LEFT JOIN FPRCategory fprcat 
        ON fpr.FPRCategoryID = fprcat.ID
```